# Android textToSpeach not working for me

Tags: android

I am trying to test the TextToSpeach engine using the tutorial from here:[Android TextToSpeach tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-using-the-text-to-speech-engine--mobile-8540)

My setup is AndroidStudio and I use a real device for testing the result.

So my app compiles fine, opens on my device just fine, I enter a text there and click on the button, but nothing happens.

- No sound can be heard besides the click sound of the button
- No error shows in the LogCat
- No Toast is showing on my device
- I have volume set on the tablet (so it's not that)
- I tryed to change the tutorial to make it say a specific sentence (to avoid the editBox) still nobody talks

What is wrong here? Do I need some permissions set for this app to work properly? I assume I would get an error somewhere if that were so...

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your main Activity class from TextToSpeech.OnInitListener

```
public class AndroidTextToSpeechActivity extends Activity implements
        TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
```

> Initialization

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

        btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);
```

> Button on click event

```
btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            speakOut();
        }


        }) ;
```

> On Init

```
   @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }

    private void speakOut() {

        String text = txtText.getText().toString();

        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
```

More Refrence :
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/

For Me its Working Well -Api Level 19

Comment: Still no talking.. :(  I do not understand... API level 20